# Electron.js quick start guide: Errors on "npm start"

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npm-scripts, npm-start

I am new to electron and followed the quick start guide here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start
My `package.json` has this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
}
```

When I run `npm start` the app starts but the versions are not printed and I get these errors in the js console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at index.html:11
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at index.html:12
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at index.html:13
```

Seems like `process` is not defined in index.html. But when I directly run `electron .` everything works correctly.

Why?

My versions:

> Manjaro 20.2.1, Kernel 5.10.18-1-MANJARO
> Node.js 15.10.0
> npm 7.6.1
> electron 12.0.0

Comment: enable node integration

Comment: As i wrote I am a beginner to electron and followed the quick start guide to the point. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `contextIsolation: false` along with `nodeIntegration: true`

Try the following:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })
```

This is being discussed here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18139

[**What is context Isolation?**](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation)

> Context Isolation is a feature that ensures that both your preload
> scripts and Electron's internal logic run in a separate context to the
> website you load in a webContents. This is important for security
> purposes as it helps prevent the website from accessing Electron
> internals or the powerful APIs your preload script has access to.
>
> This means that the window object that your preload script has access
> to is actually a different object than the website would have access
> to. For example, if you set window.hello = 'wave' in your preload
> script and context isolation is enabled window.hello will be undefined
> if the website tries to access it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I guess electron should update its tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `nodeIntegration` set to true.

**main.js**

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
```

Comment: As I wrote I followed the quick start guide and nodeIntegration is set to true. And if I call "electron ." directly it works. "npm start" which calls "electron ." does not.